# 500 при отправке FormData

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, tomcat, formdata

Проблема заключается в том, что когда я запускаю Спринг приложение у себя на ноуте все отлично работает, а когда я переношу его на сервер в Tomcat начинается интересное. Первый запрос с FormData проходит и нормально обрабатывается, все заносится в базу, но последующие запросы падают с ошибкой 500 без сообщения.

Вот пример ответа с ошибкой:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2021-12-02T22:53:08.872+00:00",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "",
    "path": "/hustle/api/catalog/add"
}
```

И вот метод контроллера который обрабатывает запрос:

```
@RequestMapping(
    value = ["add"],
    method = [RequestMethod.POST],
    consumes= ["multipart/form-data"]
)
fun add(
    @RequestParam("image") file: MultipartFile,
    @RequestParam("name") name: String,
    @RequestParam("longName") longName: String,
    @RequestParam("description") description: String,
    @RequestParam("price") price: Int
) : DataWrapper<Any> {
    return try {
        //запись в базу
    } catch(ex: Exception) {
        //вывод ошибки (не 500)
    }
}
```

Что касается настроек проекта, они полностью дефолтные за исключением пары моментов:

Добавил в настройки 3 строки, чтоб файл можно было грузить

1. **spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=10MB**
2. **spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size10MB**
3. **spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=tru***

Добавил в зависимости **spring-boot-starter-web** и убрал в настройках Tomcat ограничение на размер запроса.

Все было бы лучше, если бы оно вообще не работало, а то, что оно срабатывает первый раз, сбивает с толку.

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

**UPD**

Смог вытащить текст ошибки:

```
Failed to parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is   java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Stream ended unexpectedly
```

Comment: 500 это http код. Вся ошибка спринга написанна на стороне сервера, там в логах посмотрите с чем валится и скопируйте сюда текст.

Comment: @Mira, дополнил ответ сообщением об ошибке

Comment: Ладно, справедливый минус, это косяк томата и если бы я сразу додумался вытащить логи с сервера то сам бы все пофиксил

Comment: нормальный у вас вопрос :)

Answer (score 0):

Проблема заключается в ошибке Tomcat9, используйте Http11Nio2Protocol в , тогда не будет проблем с загрузкой файлов.